# Ant task to run an Ant target only if a file exists?

Tags: file, ant, build-automation

Is there an ANT Task that would execute a block only if a given file exists?  I have the problem that I have a generic ant script that should do some special processing but only if a specific configuration file is present.

Comment: See also [How to use wildcard in Ant's Available command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073077/how-to-use-wildcard-in-ants-available-command/)

Answer (score 207, accepted):

[Available](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html) and [Condition](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html)

```
<target name="check-abc">
    <available file="abc.txt" property="abc.present"/>
</target>

<target name="do-if-abc" depends="check-abc" if="abc.present">
    ...
</target>
```

Comment: Available is a non so obvious name for what it does.  I got further confused by the fact that google shows people writing their own tags

Comment: it may work, but does not seem like a good solution if you need to apply to a large number of files

Comment: In case anyone wondered, the `if` and `unless` attributes only enable or disable the target to which they are attached, i.e. the target's dependencies are always executed. Otherwise it would not work to depend on a target that sets the property you're checking for.

Comment: It looks like `<Available>` is deprecated. I've used this: 

`<target name="do-if-abc" if="${file::exists('abc.txt')}"> ... </target>`

check: http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/file.exists.html

Comment: @Loïc **1:** where it states that `<available>` is deprecated? **2:** `${file::existst...}` seems to be not working with Ant (Apache ANT 1.9.7)

Answer (score 123):

This might make a little more sense from a coding perspective (available with ant-contrib: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/):

```
<target name="someTarget">
    <if>
        <available file="abc.txt"/>
        <then>
            ...
        </then>
        <else>
            ...
        </else>
    </if>
</target>
```

Comment: This is only available in ant-contrib I think.

Answer (score 26):

Since Ant 1.8.0 there's apparently also resourceexists

From
http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html

> Tests a resource for existance. since
> Ant 1.8.0
>
> The actual resource to test is
> specified as a nested element.
>
> An example:
>
> ```
> <resourceexists>
>   <file file="${file}"/>
> </resourceexists>
> ```

I was about rework the example from the above good answer to this question, and then I found this

> As of Ant 1.8.0, you may instead use
> property expansion; a value of true
> (or on or yes) will enable the item,
> while false (or off or no) will
> disable it. Other values are still
> assumed to be property names and so
> the item is enabled only if the named
> property is defined.
>
> Compared to the older style, this
> gives you additional flexibility,
> because you can override the condition
> from the command line or parent
> scripts:
>
> ```
> <target name="-check-use-file" unless="file.exists">
>     <available property="file.exists" file="some-file"/>
> </target>
> <target name="use-file" depends="-check-use-file" if="${file.exists}">
>     <!-- do something requiring that file... -->
> </target>
> <target name="lots-of-stuff" depends="use-file,other-unconditional-stuff"/>
> ```

from the ant manual at http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless

Hopefully this example is of use to some.  They're not using resourceexists, but presumably you could?.....

Comment: Note that `if="${file.exists}"` should be replaced with `if="file.exists"` as `if` and `unless` check only existence of property by name, not it's value.

Comment: @Vadzim As the answer mentioned, this only works in Ant 1.8, and 1.8 does support property expansion. http://ant.apache.org/manual/properties.html#if+unless

Answer (score 13):

I think its worth referencing this similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5288804/64313

Here is a another quick solution. There are other variations possible on this using the `<available>` tag:

```
# exit with failure if no files are found
<property name="file" value="${some.path}/some.txt" />
<fail message="FILE NOT FOUND: ${file}">
    <condition><not>
        <available file="${file}" />
    </not></condition>
</fail>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Check Using Filename filters like `DB_*/**/*.sql`

Here is a variation to perform an action if one or more files exist corresponding to a wildcard filter. That is, you don't know the exact name of the file.

Here, we are looking for "***.sql**" files in any sub-directories called "**DB_***", recursively. You can adjust the filter to your needs.

**NB: Apache Ant 1.7 and higher!**

Here is the target to set a property if matching files exist:

```
<target name="check_for_sql_files">
    <condition property="sql_to_deploy">
        <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
            <fileset dir="." includes="DB_*/**/*.sql"/>
        </resourcecount>
    </condition>
</target>
```

Here is a "conditional" target that only runs if files exist:

```
<target name="do_stuff" depends="check_for_sql_files" if="sql_to_deploy">
    <!-- Do stuff here -->
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by ordering to do the operation with a list of files with names equal to the name(s) you need. It is much easier and direct than to create a special target. And you needn't any additional tools, just pure Ant.

```
<delete>
    <fileset includes="name or names of file or files you need to delete"/>
</delete>
```

See: [FileSet](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).