# How to use wildcard in Ant's Available command

Tags: java, ant

I'm using an Ant build script to collate my Eclipse-based application for distribution.

One step of the build is to check that the correct libraries are present in the build folders.  I currently use the Ant  command for this.  Unfortunately, I have to amend the script each time I switch to a new Eclipse build (since the version numbers will have updated).

I don't need to check the version numbers, I just need to check that the file's there.

So, how do I check for:

```
org.eclipse.rcp_3.5.0.*
```

instead of:

```
org.eclipse.rcp_3.5.0.v20090519-9SA0FwxFv6x089WEf-TWh11
```

using Ant?

cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You mean, something like (based on the [pathconvert task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html), after [this idea](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=109647070406692&w=2)):

```
<target name="checkEclipseRcp">
  <pathconvert property="foundRcp" setonempty="false" pathsep=" ">
    <path>
      <fileset dir="/folder/folder/eclipse"
               includes="org.eclipse.rcp_3.5.0.*" />
    </path>
  </pathconvert>
</target>

<target name="process" depends="checkEclipseRcp" if="foundRcp">
  <!-- do something -->
</target>
```

Comment: that sounds perfect - I'm dying to give it a try.

If only I'd asked the question 3 years ago, I'd have saved sooo much time.

cheers,
Ian

Answer (score 9):

A slightly shorter and more straightforward approach with [resourcecount](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/resourcecount.html) condition:

```
<target name="checkEclipseRcp">
    <condition property="foundRcp">
        <resourcecount when="greater" count="0">
            <fileset file="/folder/folder/eclipse/org.eclipse.rcp_3.5.0.*"/>
        </resourcecount>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="process" depends="checkEclipseRcp" if="foundRcp">
  <!-- do something -->
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

The pathconvert task is probably the preferred way to go in most cases.  But it creates a little problem when the directory tree is very large and one uses the echoproperties task. With a very large directory tree, the string generated by pathconvert can be huge. Then echoproperties sprays the huge string, making the output more difficult to work with. I use a macrodef on Linux that creates a property set to "1" if there are files in the directory:

```
<macrodef name="chkDirContents" >
    <attribute name="propertyName" />
    <attribute name="dirPath" />
    <attribute name="propertyFile" />
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="sh" dir="." failonerror="false" >
            <arg value="-c" />
            <arg value='fyles=`ls -1 @{dirPath} | head -1` ; if [ "$fyles" != "" ] ; then echo @{propertyName}=1 > @{propertyFile} ; fi' />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="test" >
    <tempfile destdir="." property="temp.file" deleteonexit="true" />
    <chkDirContents propertyName="files.exist" dirPath="./target_dir" propertyFile="${temp.file}" />
    <property file="${temp.file}" />

    <echoproperties/>
</target>
```

Executing the "test" target will generate the following echoproperties line if there are files in the ./target_dir/ directory:

```
[echoproperties] files.exist=1
```

What "test" does:
It generates a temporary filename, ${temp.file}, that can later be used as a property file.
It then executes the macrodef, which calls the shell to check the contents of the dirPath directory. If there are any files or directories in dirPath, it assigns the propertyName property a value of 1 in the temporary file.  It then reads the file and sets the property given in the file.  If the file is empty, no property is defined.

Note that the temporary file could be reused for subsequent calls of the macrodef if desired. On the other hand, of course, once a property is set, it is immutable.

Comment: very generous of you to step in and offer the improvement.  If only I'd been aware of this improvement 4 years ago, when I commented that I'd been aware of the base solution 3 years earlier.  

Who knows what improvement I may learn in 5 years time?