# Ant If/Unless Attribute Issue

Tags: java, ant, build, compilation, target

Forewarning, this is my first attempt at actually creating an ANT build script. I'm trying to make it so that my **test** target only runs if the `compiled` property is set to true, additionally I want my **dist** target to run unless the `junit.failure` property is set to true. But for some reason, the following code doesn't seem to be doing what I intended it to; meaning that when I try to run `ant` it will not execute tests as `compiled` is not set to true (I believe), but if I look in the bin folder I can see that the .class files were indeed generated. And consequently this means that dist will not run either as it depends on both the compile and test targets. Any thoughts or ideas on what I may be doing wrong?

```
<project name="project" default="dist" basedir="." xmlns:if="ant:if" xmlns:unless="ant:unless">
    <description>
        Build file for the project
    </description>
    <!-- set global properties for this build -->
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="lib" location="lib"/>
    <property name="bin" location="bin"/>
    <property name="dist"  location="dist"/>
    <property name="distDirName" value="dist"/>

    <!-- including the external jar files -->
    <path id="proj.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib}" includes="*.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${bin}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="compile" description="compile the source">
        <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
        <mkdir dir="${bin}"/>
        <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${bin} -->
        <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="proj.classpath" destdir="${bin}"/>
        <!-- Set condition for dependent target -->
        <condition property="compiled">
            <and>
                <available file="**/SampleTest.class"/>
                <available file="**/DBConnection.class"/>
            </and>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="compile" if="compiled">
        <junit failureproperty="junit.failure" errorproperty="junit.failure" printsummary="withOutAndErr" fork="yes" haltonfailure="true" haltonerror="true">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="this.one.dir.SampleTest" todir="${bin}"/>
            <classpath refid="proj.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="dist" depends="compile,test" unless="junit.failure" description="generate the distribution">
        <!-- Create the distribution directory -->
        <mkdir dir="${dist}"/>

        <!-- Put everything in ${bin} into the distribution.jar file -->
        <jar jarfile="${dist}/distribution.jar" basedir="${basedir}" excludes="**/test/,${distDirName}/**"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you add more details on what you intended the script to do and what it's doing instead?

Comment: You don't need all this. If compilation fails, the build will stop, so the tests won't run. If junit tests fail, the build will stop, so the dist target won't execute.

Comment: See comment from JB Nizet and btw. `ant -v test` confirms that target test is skipped if one of the `class` files are not created `Skipped because property 'compiled' not set.`

Comment: @bkail i just updated the OP with a little more detail as far as what I am currently seeing.

@JB Nizet That is what I thought myself, but this is actually for an assignment for my class and the professor told me that depends was not enough and he implied he wanted us to also use if/unless.

@SubOptimal did not think to do `ant -v`. Will have to try that when I'm at home later today, but am I doing something wrong as far as using `**/SampleTest.class"` to try and find the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use wildcard in Ant's Available command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073077/how-to-use-wildcard-in-ants-available-command)

Comment: As I flagged it, you can find the answer in that other question. So everything is okay with your script, you just can't use wildcards such simple way.

Answer (score 0):

you need to evaluate your variable, use `${junit.failure}` for instance

```
<target name="dist" depends="compile,test" unless="${junit.failure}" description="generate the distribution"> 
</target>
```