# Verify that ant-contrib.jar is available before doing a build?

Tags: ant, jar, ant-contrib

Ant-Contrib is required for some parts of the build.xml so we first want to check if ant has the jar for it in its directory, and download and unpack it to the right directory if its not.

Any thoughts to this end is helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists) to check if the file exists and [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/get.html) to download the file.