# subant on condition

Tags: ant

I'd like to execute subant on some condition. something like:

```
<if>
<equals value="value1" property="${some.property">
<then>
  <subant target="@{target}" failonerror="true" inheritall="false">
    <buildpath refid="some-ref1" />
  </subant>
</then>
<else>
  <subant target="@{target}" failonerror="true" inheritall="false">
          <buildpath refid="some-ref2" />
  </subant>
</else>
</if>
```

But can't find a way to do it. Read the ant manual and googled, but no solution is found.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the error may lie in your equals tag.  Instead of using the 'value' and 'propery' attributes, try using 'arg1' and 'arg2', i.e.:

```
<equals arg1="value1" arg2="${some.property}">
```

Check out the examples in the ant-contrib doc: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html.

If the problem is that your 'if', 'then', and/or 'else' tags are not resolving properly, then you may be missing the ant-contrib libraries. Ant-contrib is not natively included with ant, but you can download it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ant-contrib/files/

Per the ant-contrib site (http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), here's what you must do to install ant-contrib:

Option 1: Copy ant-contrib-0.3.jar to the lib directory of your Ant installation. If you want to use one of the tasks in your own project, add the lines

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties"/>
```

to your build file.

Option 2: Keep ant-contrib-0.3.jar in a separate location. You now have to tell Ant explicitly where to find it (say in /usr/share/java/lib):

```
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement location="/usr/share/java/lib/ant-contrib-0.3.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

Comment: Ant doesn't recognize 'if' tag.

Comment: Vladimir, perhaps your problem is that the ant-contrib libraries are not included on ant's classpath.  I've modified my response, above, to include info on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Please look up a `<target if="${some.property}>`. You may want another target with an `unless`.

If the property has to do with a file existing, see [Ant task to check a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/520546/509840). Even if this is not your main concern, I am sure you can get the idea from the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean calling another target
if so here is

```
<if> 
<equals value="value1" property="${some.property">
<then>
<antcall target="@{target}" failonerror="true" inheritall="false">
 </then>
<else>
  <antcall target="@{target}" failonerror="true" inheritall="false">


</else>
</if>
```

Comment: Ant doesn't recognize 'if' tag.