# ant target to run only based on condition

Tags: ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ant task to check if a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists)

```
<target name="buildjunit">      
    <mkdir dir="${BUILD_TEST_DIR}" />
    <ant antfile="build.xml" dir="${app}\dcs" target="compile-junit" inheritAll="false">
        <property name="BUILD" value="${COMP_BUILD}" />
        <property name="VER" value="${PREVIOUS_VERSION}" />
        <property name="build.local" value="true" />
        <property name="CONFIG" value="${CONFIG_HOME}/ESW/ESWCONFIG/ITT" />
    </ant>
</target>
```

I want to build ant target compile-junit only if some of the jar doesnt exist in perticulary directory, how can i do it? ie compile-junit target inside buidljunit should run only when there is no jar file exist in the directory project/jarlocation/dcs.

Comment: This looks like the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight variation to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists) I commented as similar. To run when it doesn't exist replace 'if' with 'unless':

```
<target name="check-abc">
    <available file="abc.txt" property="abc.present"/>
</target>

<target name="do-unless-abc" depends="check-abc" unless="abc.present">
    ...
</target>
```

Comment: You can check the folder doesn't exist like this <available file="/project/jarlocation/dcs" type="dir" property="abc.present"/>