# Check the existence file in ant

Tags: ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ant task to check if a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists)

How can one check if a file exist in a directory, if not use another file in different location. I tried the follow but does not help me with what I want. Could someone help?

```
 <condition property="somefile.available">
     <or>
         <available file="/home/doc/somefile"/>
         <and>
             <available file="/usr/local/somefile" />
         </and>
     </or>
 </condition>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use condition tests to establish if files are present. Then have a target for each true condition

```
<target name="go" depends="file-checks, do-something-with-first-file, do-something-with-second-file"/>

<target name="file-checks">
   <available file="/home/doc/somefile"  property="first.file.found"/>
   <available file="/usr/local/somefile" property="second.file.found"/>
</target>

<target name="do-something-with-first-file" if="first.file.found">
   ???
</target>

<target name="do-something-with-second-file" if="second.file.found">
   ???
</target>
```

Answer (score 12):

If you don't mind using ant-contrib you can take the procedural approach like this:

```
  <if>
    <available file="file1"/>
    <then>
      <property name="file.exists" value="true"/>
    </then>
    <else>
      <if>
        <available file="file2"/>
        <then>
          <copy file="file2" tofile="file1"/>
          <property name="file.exists" value="true"/>
        </then>
      </if>
    </else>
  </if>
```

Otherwise you can probably use a target that is conditional on a property being set to indicate whether the file already exists in the preferred location, like [Ant task to run an Ant target only if a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists/520567#520567) but using `unless` instead of `if`.

Comment: Thanks Ben for your reply.Actually what I want to achieve is that we check both files and if the first file does not exist ie /home/doc/somefile then we can copy the second one to that directory.

Comment: we check both files and if the first file does not exist ie /home/doc/somefile then we can copy the second one to that directory. For example <copy todir= "/home/doc/ file=/usr/local/somefile" overwrite="false"/>. This seems not working.

Comment: Thanks Mark and Ben. I manage to come out with a solution from the ideas I got from you guys