# How to check if files in one directory exist in another directory?

Tags: ant

I am looking for a means to have Ant check a target directory for the existence of files in a list/set defined by a source directory.

The Ant target only needs to determine if the files in a source directory also currently exist in the target directory.  No copying/moving/deleting necessary.

Can this be done in Ant?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-check-if-a-file-exists

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Ant [resource collection set operators](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#difference).  For example:

```
<fileset id="source" dir="source_dir" />
<fileset id="target" dir="target_dir" />

<difference id="difference">
    <resources refid="source"/>
    <resources refid="target"/>
</difference>

<echo message="${toString:difference}" />
```

You can use a [dirset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) if you're only interested in directories.