# to check if the file is available or not in ant

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

Requirement : to check if the file is available or not and then based on true or false value perform some task.

I am using  task:

```
<varNested name="path" value="/user1/abc.jar"/>
<available file="${path}" property="file.available"/>
```

Problem 1:
Now when I am trying to print this property:

```
<echo message="value of file is available is : ${file.available}"/>
```

rather than printing the value true it prints ${file.available}

Problem 2:
Will this code snippet work? if not, what shall be used instead of equalsNested?
    
             
            
               ...

```
        </then>
        <else>
           ...
        </else>
        </if>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ant task to run an Ant target only if a file exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520546/ant-task-to-run-an-ant-target-only-if-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<property name="abc" value="false" />
<available file="somefile" property="abc" value="true"/>
<echo message="value of file is available is : ${abc}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Guidance... With the code above, it complains that I am trying to set the value of the same property 2 time. but this works:                                         `<property name="abc" value="false" />
<available file="somefile" property="abc" />
<echo message="value of file is available is : ${abc}"/>`